# Counting duplicated values in String array

Tags: java, string

Can someone tell me how I can count duplicate values in String array?

For example:

```
String [] names = {"Caty", "John", "Nick", "John", "Philip", "Caty", "Caty"};
```

The returned value should be 5 because Caty appears 3 times and John 2 times.

Thank you

Comment: Compare all of them and keep a count.

Comment: How would you do it in real life?

Comment: before answering your question with various possible ways to do this: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Just remember that you do not use `==` to compare Strings but use `equals` method instead.

Comment: Or you can solve it with 3 rows : creating a Set, adding all array's contents to it by Collections.addAll and subtracting set's length from array length. But seriously, it is an awful way)

Comment: @oleg.lukyrych this would tell you how many duplicates you have but it wouldn't count in original objects so result would be 3 in this case.

Comment: @Pshemo i just looked at the question header. There was "Counting duplicated values in String array"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would insert the names into a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the name and the value is the count of times that name has been inserted. In other words, for each name look it up in the map to get the previous count. If it is not found, the previous count is 0. Add one to the previous count and `put(name, newCount)` back into the map. When you are done adding names, iterate over the entry set and sum the counts that are greater than one (if I understood your counting methodology).

```
String[] names = ...
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(names.length);
for (String name : names) {
   Integer count = map.get(name);
   if (count == null) {
       count = 0;
   }
   map.put(name, count + 1);
}
int count = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
      count += entry.getValue();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] names = {"Caty", "John", "Nick", "John", "Philip", "Caty", "Caty"};
    HashMap<String, Integer> repeatNames = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    int repeatCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < names.length; k++) {
            if (names[i] == names[k]) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > 1) {
            if (!repeatNames.containsKey(names[i])) {
                System.out.println(names[i] + ":" + count);
                repeatNames.put(names[i], count);
                repeatCount += count;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Count:" + repeatCount);
}
```

Ouput

```
Caty:3
John:2
Total Count:5
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply concept of nested loops .

In first loop iterate over the array and take the ith element and in next loop check that element in entire array and store them in map for duplicate values

```
String[] names = {"Caty", "John"........}

Map<String, int> duplicateMap = new HashMap<String, int>();
for (i = 0; i <= names.length; i++) {
    String x = names[i];
    int count = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <= names.length; j++) {
        if (x.equals(names[j])
        count++;
    }
    duplicateMap.put(x, count);
}
```

Then this map will have all info which all elements are duplicate and whats their duplicate count.

Comment: This method will perform badly if the list of names gets large.